# How to automatically export data from TestLink

Tags: selenium, export, testlink

I would like to export data from TestLink but automatically and on daily basis.
Is that somehow possible in TestLink itself or I really must use Selenium or familiar software?

Comment: Did you google this question? What did you find? What are you missing to accomplish this task?

Comment: Yes, I did. All I have found was just about how to get automatically the data TO TestLink, not FROM.
And even here I didn't found answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You use the api of testlink. Check the [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/TestLink-API-Python-client/0.4.7), it is for python client, or you can find your favorite language. You can write script/[crone job](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) or similar to perform daily base activity.